# Pandas Dataframe add row to new df on x condition in series then delete row in

Tags: python, pandas

I need help doing the following and I am confident there is a simpler way to do it with Pandas than how I have tried.

If a specific "cell" in a series meets a condition I want to a) add the entire row to a separate Dataframe, then b) delete the row from the first Dataframe.

Is there a concise way to do this?

I have been foundering with bad for loop solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add sample data to this question along with expected outputs?

Comment: I can't because it's internal data. Many apologies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create a mask that meets your condition.
mask = df['column_name'].eq('hello world')

# Make a new DataFrame using this mask.
new_df = df.loc[mask]

# Remove these rows from the original DataFrame.
df = df.loc[~mask]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I am going to research this mask approach. Looks very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Another name for this is [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), here's a link to the Panda's documentation on the topic.